# Best Practice with Angular Service that depends on another Angular Service?

Tags: angular, observable, azure-ad-msal

I'm unsure of what is a best practice on how to deal with an Angular service that depends on another Angular service to retrieve the right information from the backend.

My project is setup like this:

**Service 1 - Auth.service.ts**
This service uses the Microsoft MSAL library to authenticate and store user info (Name, ID, email, etc.) in a User class.

**Service 2 - WorkPlace.service.ts**
This service is the backbone of the application and gets relevant information to the user who logs in (meeting schedule, project info, etc.).  It depends on the user logging in and the User info coming back with the User ID so it can bring back relevant WorkPlace info on that user.

I have various components that inject the WorkPlace.service.ts service in to get the WorkPlace data from the backend and display them on the front end.  Example:  I have a Project.component.ts that has a WorkPlace service in the constructor so it can call a function called "GetProjects()" to get that user's project information.

### Question

I'm unsure on whether I should the logic to get the current user info in each component that needs to pull back info about that user or in the WorkPlace.service.ts that actually retrieves the info from the backend about a user.  To clarify, I think there are two options:

**Option #1** - Have the individual components, Ex: Project.component.ts, use the Auth service to get the User ID and then pass that into the WorkPlace.service.ts to get relevant information about that user's project.  Ex:  GetProject(userId: number).

**Option #2** - Have a subscription to the Auth.service.ts setup in the WorkPlace.service.ts so any call from any component will use the current user's information.

Comment: Option 1 is useful , you can go for it

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell without seeing the whole code and understand the concept but i would go with Options #2 since it's more DRY.
I think using observables and pipe you can build some nice code.
Injecting a service in another service is generally not a big problem, you just need to be careful to not build a circular dependency